# Image based menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial here:
http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/image-rollover-menu-19/

Yet I only get the bullet pointed list without the images.

I have verified my CSS file is being included as I can change the background color of the entire page.

I have verified I can include images on my main page using the  tag, with urls like the following: "img/nav/nav_news.png" These are the same URLs I'm using for the menu.

I have tried enclosing the url inside the url() sections of my stylesheet in quotes, and without quotes.

I have also tried expanding the width and height of the menu in the CSS file, guessing maybe the width and height was too small for my images (which are 140x50 pixels) but no luck there either.

Any ideas why this might not work? My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">

<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png"
      href="favicon.png">

<link rel="shortcut icon" 
      type="image/png"
      href="favicon.png">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
      type="text/css"
      href="all.css"> 

<title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="news"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li class="merch"><a href="#">Merch</a></li>
        <li class="shows"><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

And my all.css:

```
.menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
        list-style: none;
        background: #fff;
}

.menu li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 70px;
        list-style: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.menu li a, .menu li a:visited {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        height: 70px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.news {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_news.png");}
.news a {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_news.png");}
.merch {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_merch.png");}
.merch a {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_merch.png");}
.shows {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_shows.png");}
.shows a {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_shows.png");}
.contact {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_contact.png");}
.contact a {background-image: url("img/nav/nav_contact.png");}

ul.menu li a:hover {background: none;}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: create a snippet or fiddle

Comment: i would suggest you to check the background image file paths if they are correct or not

Comment: Thanks folks. My css file wasn't getting loaded. o_O It works now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove this style from your code: text-indent: -9999px; and verify image path once again.